# "not a valid month" even though other datetype operations work

Tags: sql, oracle, date, sysdate

So, I have seen some similar questions asked here but none of the solutions have worked for me. In a view, I generate a datetype field by doing:

```
TO_DATE(DataOraModifica, 'YYYYMMDDhh24miss')
```

I'm querying this view and I want to find all entries more recent than 15 days. but when I try this:

```
select  dataoramodifica, sysdate-dataoramodifica as dife from myview 
where sysdate-dataoramodifica<15
```

but I get this error:
ORA-01843: not a valid month
01843. 00000 -  "not a valid month"

I have read on other posts that it can be related to to_char and to_date conversions as well as the session time format. But I'm not using any to_char, just one to_date directly on my original string

Actually, if I try other operations, such as:

```
select  dataoramodifica, sysdate-dataoramodifica as dife from myview
where rownum<10
```

I do get a result that makes sense:

13-AUG-16   1426.998530092592592592592592592592592593

the only problem comes when I try to use this operations for a WHERE condition.
I've tried doing to_char and to_date to convert everyithing to the same format and back again, with no result. I would like to avoid altering the session date format since for my view I use some stored procedures related to date (and which I'm not allowed to modify) and this is a working system so I wouldn't want to cause trouble.

Thank you

----Edit----

I don't seem to be handling all the cases in which TO_DATE may fail when using:

```
length(F_Convert2NormalDate(dataoramodifica))=14 then 
TO_DATE(F_Convert2NormalDate(DataOraModifica), 'YYYYMMDDhh24miss') 
else TO_DATE('19000101000000', 'YYYYMMDDhh24miss') end
AS DATAORAMODIFICA
```

To see which possible values I have I did:

```
  select distinct 
substr(f_convert2normaldate(dataoramodifica), 5,2) as mms, from mytable
```

and the values I got were:

(null)
00
01
02
03
04
05
06
07
08
09
10
11
12

I guess I need to find a way to handle all possible conversion errors cause there are clearly some that I'm missing. The  `default` option won't do cause I'm running version 11...

----Edit---

As most of you suggested, there was a case where conversion was failing even after my 14-character check ('19000000000000'). After adding this to my ´case...then´ it works. It still feels like a hardcoded solution though, but I guess for now that'll have to do since the version I'm running doesn't allow for generic exception handling (such as ´default... on conversion error´ ) and I think the problem must be handled at the data-generation stage by those in charge of it.

Thanks everyone for your help!

Comment: In your example "mytable" is the name of the view ?

Comment: yes, just as an example. I'll correct it for clarity, thanks!

Comment: `DataOraModifica` is actually a date in your table `table` but you are trying to convert it to date again in your view `mytable` using `to_date`. why? if you want your view to show date in the `'YYYYMMDDhh24miss'` format then you must use the `to_char` in your view. You are trying to convert a date to again in a date.

Comment: Ok, then please answer me this: when you go to the last row in the result that will give you this query: "select * from myview" do you get this same error ?

Comment: It's a string in its original table, I convert it to a date only once when creating the view. I changed the names on the code snippets for clarity, sorry.

Comment: Can you provide sample data set from your view, would be helpful to understand the issue

Comment: It may take a while if I do a select * from the view without constraints, but it works if I load 1000 lines or so

Comment: @Fernanda I wanted to check if there is a problem with some of the data in your table because your query will go through the whole view and if there is some value in your table with non valid character set(set of character that is not in a format of a date you are converting it to) I believe that then you will get this error... Your second select gives you only the first 10 rows and that is why it works...

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name but the OP already explained that the value in a table is string and then in a view it is converted to date ...

Comment: @VBoka: my understanding is that Fernanda is querying the _view_ where `dataoramodifica` has been converted to a proper `date` column (with the same name)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yes. the original table has "dataoramodifica" as a string. My view applies to_date to it. I'm afterwards querying such view and that's when I get the error.

Comment: I am now confused. She has a table with a column that is of   varhcar data type and a value in that column like : '20200405222222'. Then she creates a view and she converts that value by using to_date in a view query for example: `create view myview (col2) as select to_date(column_from_table, 'YYYYMMDDhh24miss') from table` then she does this: `selec col2 from myview where sysdate-col2<15` and this gives her the error. If this is all true I do not see where is she sending date format value to a to_date function ?

Comment: It's exactly as @VBoka says. The only timeI use to_date I'm giving it a string that has not suffered any conversion related to a date datatype.

Comment: @Fernanda - "values I got were:(null) 00 ..." - well 00 isn't a valid month, so look at the rows that give you that substring; both the original value and what the function returns. I still suspect it's returning 14 zeros not 2, at least sometimes? You'll have to decide if the function is broken, or if you aren't handling something it's expected to return.

Comment: yup, a few rows (like 4 out of 1.6 million!) have '19000000000000', so this was breaking my length check. Trying to see if sorting this out fixes it, but I don't love the idea of hardcoding it. I'll try to talk with the guys that did the F_Convert2NormalDate

Answer (score 3):

> the stored procedure ... takes a string produced by the system that is encoded somehow, and returns another string in the way YYYYMMDDhhmmss, if the input does not produce a valid date it returns the string "00".

If it actually returns '00000000000000' (or, [as it turns out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62829484/not-a-valid-month-even-though-other-datetype-operations-work#comment111114477_62829484), '19000000000000') then those will cause that error:

```
select to_date('00000000000000', 'YYYYMMDDhh24miss') from dual;

ORA-01843: not a valid month

select to_date('19000000000000', 'YYYYMMDDhh24miss') from dual;

ORA-01843: not a valid month
```

When you query the view without the condition you are either limiting to 10 indeterminate rows with `where rownum<10` as you showed, or your client is only fetching and displaying the 'first' few rows or blocks of rows (e.g. 50 rows by default in SQL Developer). The procedure (which is actually a function, presumably...) is only called for those few rows, which happen to not contain any problematic data.

When you have the condition every row has to be evaluated, so you are hitting a problematic one.

You can avoid the issue by changing the view to do something like:

```
TO_DATE(
  case
    when DataOraModifica = '00' then null
    when DataOraModifica = '00000000000000' then null
    when DataOraModifica = '19000000000000' then null
    else DataOraModifica
  end, 
  'YYYYMMDDhh24miss'
)
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=aaae5b913d47110eed95b5896f6cfcae)

Incidentally, I'd normally write the condition as

```
where dataoramodifica >= trunc(sysdate) - 15;
```

which has to do less work and would allow an index on the column to be used; which isn't likely to matter here as the view column is a function call anyway.  Using `trunc(sysdate)` will include all data from that start date, rather than just from the current time on that date - it's unclear which you actually want.

---

Looking at the length check you were already doing, you could incorporate that as:

```
case when length(F_Convert2NormalDate(DataOraModifica)) != 14
       or F_Convert2NormalDate(DataOraModifica) = '00'
       or F_Convert2NormalDate(DataOraModifica) = '00000000000000'
       or F_Convert2NormalDate(DataOraModifica) = '19000000000000'
     then date '1900-01-01'
     else TO_DATE(DataOraModifica, 'YYYYMMDDhh24miss')
end
```

Or if you're on a recent version of Oracle (12.2+) you can let `to_date()` handle any error condition:

```
TO_DATE(DataOraModifica default '19000101000000' on conversion error,
  'YYYYMMDDhh24miss')
```

It's possible that will hide other issues you would want to actually throw an error, so you know there is somethign you need to fix, but it doesn't sound like it from your description.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ff7120ce725b46f05500c77bfcdec338)

---

To identify values which are causing a problem, you can do something like this:

```
set serveroutput on
declare
  str varchar2(30);
  dt date;
begin
  for r in (select dataoramodifica from mytable) loop
    begin
      str := F_Convert2NormalDate(r.DataOraModifica);
      dt := case when length(str) = 14
                 then TO_DATE (str, 'YYYYMMDDhh24miss')
                 else TO_DATE('19000101000000', 'YYYYMMDDhh24miss')
            end;
    exception
      when others then
        dbms_output.put_line(r.DataOraModifica || ' -> ' || str || ' => ' || sqlerrm);
    end;
  end loop;
end;
/
```

That will try to convert every value in the table one by one; when it finds a problem it will report it but carry on. You can add other useful data in the debug of course, like the row's primary key value.

Comment: I had run the query over all registries before and I don't get an error if I do it without the WHERE condition. I tried reproducing your example exactly as you did and I still got the error :( is it possible that it has something to do with SQL Developer?

Comment: @Fernanda - only in terms of how many rows are fetched. Running it as a query, so the results are in a grid, only fetches 50 rows at a time, so you would have to scroll right to the end to make sure all rows had been evaluated. Running as a script stops after 5000 rows by default. I'm unclear if you've seen all rows, but you said it takes a while.

Comment: @Fernanda - it's unlikely but I suppose it's possible you're hitting a bug with predicate pushing, though I don't see how with the function call in there. What exact version and patch level of Oracle are you using?

Comment: I guess something else to check is what result or error you get from `select count(*), max(DataOraModifica) from myview`?

Comment: ok I did get an error without the condition when scrolling to the bottom. the `default on conversion` part doesn't seem to work for the version I'm running, and maybe the error is being caused by conditions I'm not handling with the `if ... then` is there another way to catch possible errors so that I can tell it what to do if it can't convert it?

Comment: You should probably figure out which rows are causing the problem rather than trying to suppress them; I've added a PL/SQL block that ought to give you some idea.

Comment: @Fernanda - also realised that the length check you said you're doing is wrong; not sure how accurate the code you added as a comment is though, since it has other mistakes. Verify and correct that if necessary, and see if it fixes the problem.

Comment: you're right,  I had seen these mistakes and sorted them out, I copied the wrong code snippet...

Comment: What I meant is: you said "if you're running a recent version..." and I don't seem to be so I was asking if there was some equivalent to handle conversion errors in general, didn't mean I wanted to supress rows

Comment: @Fernanda - you fixed the typos, or also the `length()` call, as in my last edit? It would probably have been useful to include the code you're actually using in the question. Have you run the PL/SQL block (which checks the right length) and did it report any errors? (And no, there isn't a way to suppress errors in 12.1 and earlier as part of the query; but I think that's what your function is trying to do.)

Comment: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

Answer (score 2):

I believe the problem is in your data from your table.
You say there is a column with string values and you convert that string to date and then you use this converted column in select and wheer clause.

Here is a example of your possible situation:

If theer is a good string in your table like '20200405222222' then your query will work:

```
select  to_date('20200405222222', 'YYYYMMDDhh24miss')
        , sysdate-to_date('20200405222222', 'YYYYMMDDhh24miss') as dife 
from dual;
```

If the string is like '20201305222222' then your query will not work:

```
select  to_date('20201305222222', 'YYYYMMDDhh24miss')
        , sysdate-to_date('20201305222222', 'YYYYMMDDhh24miss') as dife 
from dual;
```

[Here is a small demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=485fe7180a4892f441f8036db16ac153)

You can see from my example that Ihave used 13 as a numeric string to represent the month and that is not a valid month...

Here is an even better example where I have created a view and used two different query's:

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=1f70f43aef1297044261ca813b8022bc

Comment: this initial string is actually generated by a store procedure, whose only possible outputs are a 14 character "good" string or "00". To sort this out, what actually happens in the view is:

Comment: case when
length(dataoramodifica)=14 then 
TO_DATE ((F_Convert2NormalDate(DataOraModifica), 'YYYYMMDDhhmiss') 
else 
TO_DATE('19000101000000', 'YYYYMMDDhhmiss') end as
AS DATAORAMODIFICA,

Comment: And what does this do : F_Convert2NormalDate ?

Comment: this is the stored procedure I mentioned which I have no access to, but it takes a string produced by the system that is encoded somehow, and returns another string in the way YYYYMMDDhhmmss, if the input does not produce a valid date it returns the string "00". I think the important thing is that no date datatypes are involved up tho this point, so I wouldn't think it affects what I do after with the conversions

Comment: Hi @Fernanda, If the string is 14 characters long this does not mean that it is a valid date string.Just do as I have proposed: `select * from my view`  and then go to the last value... of the result set. Trust me it will show you error soon...

Comment: I understand, but the stored procedure that produces it is supposed to ensure it actually is valid. I know I shouldn't blindly trust it but when I run the view (or query it without doing comparisons) it doesn't produce any error. The problem happens specifically when I try using it for calculations within the WHERE clause

Comment: What tool do you use ? SQL developer ? Toad ? Something else ?

Comment: @Fernanda - when you query the view without the condition you are only looking at a few values; in your example 10 indeterminate rows, but even without that your client may be paging the results. If you query and fetch/display every row then it will still error, when it reaches the bad value. Also, for an invalid date, does the procedure actually return '00' or '00000000000000'?

Comment: Thanks @AlexPoole -  Exactly what I tried to explain in one of my comments...I agree

Comment: I have queried over all of the data before (with no error), I just meant that to answer your question quickly it'd take a while if I did it again. The stored procedure returns 00 but thats why I -sorta harcoded-made it so that when I have 00 it inputs '19000101000000'. Querying over all rows (calling the conversion over all the data) with no limits gives me no error , the only time it happens is when I try to compare it to sysdate on my WHERE clause

Comment: Hi @Fernanda, sorry, just to make sure: "I have queried over all of the data before (with no error)" means that you have selected all from the view and then you have "scrolled" all the way down to the last row of data from the view ?

Comment: Hi @Fernanda, Please run this query on your table : `select substr(column1, 1, 4), substr(column1, 5, 2), substr(column1, 7, 2) from test where substr(column1, 5, 2) > 12` where column1 is the colum where you have your date string saved...

Comment: @VBoka query returned 0 lines. Double-checking the "scroll" part

Comment: @Fernanda you have a shortcut for the "scroll part" in SQL developer. First click with your mouse anywhere in the query result grid and press ctrl+End buttons on your keyboard to go to the last row of the query results

Comment: ok so I did get an error after a certain amount of lines. is there any sort of "try catch" I could do so as to set a default value when conversion fails? (without knowing the specific ways in which it can fail, cause it seems there are cases I'm not considering)

Comment: For start please can you give me two or three examples of strings from table(original strings before conversion).

Comment: @Fernanda it ijust to see the original format of string so I can write some proposla for detecting the problem....

Comment: @VBoka if I have indeed found all possible cases by now, it can either be '00', '19000000000000' or any _correct_ date such as '20140507083000', '20200708123400', '20170809231500'.... (dates range from around mid 2014 up to now. Hours are in a 24 hour format.

Comment: Hi @Fernanda, In the  table ?